# Dynamic multiple Like AND query search against a collection of text fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Alright.. this is both an interesting solution, and a question of "is there a better way to do this".

I have a database table of addresses, broken into various fields (name, phone, suite, address, etc..)
we want to be able to do a very loose search against the address records, with multiple parameters.
so if someone searches "123 Mac", that's an easy enough match against an address.. but if they search for "David lincoln", where the name is "David something" and the address is "123 lincoln park", that's a much trickier search.
I came across another post where someone used a cross apply for search parameters, which I though was just nifty, so I fashioned something similar.
I take the user search string, and break it into values (split) on the spaces, and insert that into a temp table in memory.

On the search table, I've created a somewhat constrained view, with a "searchText" column where I've literally mashed all the conceivable search fields into one big text field.  I then created an index on this view. (had to force the use of the view/index, which does perform substantially better than the engine attempting to build a plan against the underlying tables)

And finally the query:

```
create table #searchValues (SString varchar(100) null) 
insert into  #searchValues (sstring) select '%'+[value]+'%' from dbo.Split(ltrim(rtrim(replace(@searchstring,'%',' '))),' ')

select top 50 addressID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.[3mUsage] desc, searchText) AS RowNumber
from vwAddressSearch a WITH (NOEXPAND)
cross apply #searchValues s
where searchText like s.SString 
group by addressID, [3musage], searchText
having count(*) = (select count(*) from #searchValues)
```

So this works well enough... (I take the output of this query and re-join it back to the main table to pull all the relevant values)

Also note this is an AND logic, not an OR, which is why I'm having to group and compare counts.

But the somewhat fugly part.. that indexed view is still around 900k rows, and the more search terms there are, the more cross apply and text searching there ends up being.. the performance is .. okay.. not great, not horrible.
it actually seems to perform slightly better than a manual select where... searchtext like '%one%' and searchtext like '%two%'.. etc.

Anyway, the question here, the group by and count compare, it works.. but it seems a little ugly to me.  is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Perfomance is never going to be great like that, you're working horizontally you need to be working vertically. I would break your searchable terms into rows and populate a custom index, clustered on the column of search terms. you can then cross-apply search against this, counting matching rows. Performance would be quick, especially if you used hekaton in-memory table. Rebuild the index nightly and nibble at it with a trigger.

Comment: Paul White has [a great article](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) where he builds a trigram index (3-letter blocks). Sounds like you need a similar idea with whole words (depends whether you want to search inside words or not). I reckon Paul's idea could be implemented with an indexed view joined to a tally/numbers table.